# how to stop the browser retying the get request in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

Is there any simple way I can stop the browser from retying the get request. I have the following route that does quite a bit of work and takes between three and four minutes but after about two minutes the browser retries again from the start. Is there any setting I could send in a header or something that can stop this browser behavior.

```
router.get('/notLoading', middleware.requireAuthentication, function(req, res) {
    util.getImagesLinkedInQuestions().then(function (images) {
        res.render('images', {page_name: 'images', admin: req.session.admin, admin_uid: req.session.admin_uid , images: images});
    }); 
});
```

Comment: If the request takes that long, it shouldn't be handled as a single request. A simple request should start an asynchronous background task which does the heavy lifting; the browser can refresh the page or something to check on the status of the background task, but that does not re-trigger the task. When finished, the browser can refresh the page to see the result.

Comment: You could play with cache-headers or response statuses

Comment: yeah I tried starting it then send a response but unsure how to send a second response when  the work is done. I was running into request headers already sent error

Comment: You can't send a second response. If you need real time notifications you need to start using websockets or similar. With simple HTTP, the client will have to check back in certain intervals to ask the server how it's going with the background task.

Comment: Okay I will have to look into sockets so if that's the only way. Thanks